# How to set up php-fmt code formatter in Atom text editor on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, atom-editor, formatter

I have big trouble to run php-fmt plugin in Atom. This plugin needs fmt.phar and php 5.6 install in system.
First problem: how to install fmt.phar
Second problem: after solve first problem in my mac console when I type 'php -v' i see PHP 5.6.12 but plugin steel do not work.

I found the answer to this problem but I have published it here for future generations which may have a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem:
Go to [php.tools](https://github.com/Shaked/php.tools/blob/master/fmt.phar) and click “Download ZIP” (last option in menu on the right). After download, unzip file and go to created directory in console and type:

```
mv fmt.phar /usr/local/bin/fmt.phar
```

Second problem: The atom see diffrent php vestion than system console. Run Atom, push cmd+alt+i (the chrome-like console will open) and copy into console line (at the bottom) (BTW: atom console allow you to see errors when you run plugins):

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec; 
var cmd = 'php -v'; 
exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) { console.log(error,stdout,stderr) });
```

If you will see PHP 5.5 this mean that somewhere in system you have still this version of php. Change 'php -v' to 'echo $PATH'

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec; 
var cmd = 'echo $PATH'; 
exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) { console.log(error,stdout,stderr) });
```

And you will see path that Atom see. For instance i saw:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

And in /usr/bin I had wrong wersion of php. So i go there and change to right by commands (in system console):

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo rm php
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.15/bin/php php
```

After that, run Atom, go to php-fmt plugin settings and set:

```
Executable path (fmt): /usr/local/bin/fmt.phar
```

And you're done :)

Comment: In new versions of php-fmt plugin there is place where you can put path to php - so you don't need to change php in /usr/bin directory.